# Keep Android application active on screen timeout

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity, timeout

I'm fairly new to making Android application so I got a question.

If I got my application running and I wait for a few seconds my screen timeouts. The problem is that when I unlock my screen again my application is closed. I want the application to stay active when the screen times out, so that I don't have to start the application all over again.

I don't want the application to run in the background and also I do not want to disable the screen timeout. I just don't want the application to close itself after the screen automatically times out.

Is there any chance of doing so?

_EDIT > Added some of my code.

**Android Manifest**

```
    <supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"
    />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <application
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <activity
                    android:name=".SIOM_AndroidActivity"
                    android:label="@string/app_name"
                    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" 
                    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
                    <intent-filter>
                            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                    </intent-filter>
            </activity>     
            <activity 
                    android:name="com.phonegap.DroidGap" 
                    android:label="@string/app_name" 
                    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" > 
                    <intent-filter> 
                    </intent-filter> 
            </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Android Activity**

```
package com.siom.android;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.JsResult;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import com.phonegap.*;

public class SIOM_AndroidActivity extends DroidGap {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    /** @Override */
    WebView mWebView;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            super.init();
            super.clearCache();
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
            mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
            mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
            mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());

            mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com/test.html");
    }

    // Maakt een WebChromeClient class aan
    final Context myApp = this;
    final class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

        // Zorgt er voor dat confirm werkt in WebView
        @Override
        public boolean onJsConfirm(WebView view, String url, String message, final JsResult result) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(myApp)
            .setTitle("Title here")
            .setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                    {
                        result.confirm();
                    }
                })
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                    {
                        result.cancel();
                    }
                })
            .create()
            .show();
                 return true;
        }

        // Zorgt er voor dat alert werkt in WebView
        @Override
        public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, final JsResult result) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(myApp)
            .setTitle("Title here")
            .setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                new AlertDialog.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                    {
                        result.confirm();
                    }
                })
            .setCancelable(false)
            .create()
            .show();
                 return true;
        }
    }
    // Alle links worden in webview geladen
    private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }

    // Geeft de back knop een goback actie
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After so many hours, days, weeks and even months trying to solve this problem I finally found it.

If you look at the code I added in my first post you can see the follow two lines of code:

```
super.init();
super.clearCache();
```

These two little guys crashed my application over and over and now after I look at it it's no wonder they did. Added these because I was first working with PhoneGap and followed some tutorial somewhere that told me to add these lines. After removing these two lines again my application worked as usual again. Only removing one line didn't work either.

Sometimes programming can really be a hell.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct answer to ur question. Have a look at [Figure 1. The activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html)

The concept says that when screen is locked your activity is no longer visible (onPause()). When screen is turned back on onResume() is called. You can use these methods to get the desired results.

Generally, I initialize everything onCreate() of the activity and refresh the values if any onResume().

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response, but just to clear things up. If my phone goes on lockscreen, the application just disappears and when I unlock my screen I don't see the application anymore. Doesn't that mean that my application is not paused but just stopped? I can't really resume my application if its not running anymore, right?

Comment: that's strange u cannot see ur app after unlocking the screen. May be u've added some additional flag like `android:noHistory='true'`. It'll be helpful if you post come code here.

Comment: I added my manifest and activity. Hope this will help some more, but I don´t see anything strange in it.